# PHP form with response on same page

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, contacts

Hi I created a PHP form - I am getting the email but the the response message opens in the same window with plain text. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

This is the output once submitted:

{"status":"success","message":"Thank you for your interest in Nature's Apprentice.
A representative will be in contact with you shortly","email_sent":true}

This is the contact form code:

```
<form name="formContact" id="formContact" action="contact-submit.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

            <label for="name">Name <span class="required" >*</span></label>
            <input name="name" id="name" class="form-control " placeholder="First and Last Name" type="text">

            <label for="email">Email <span class="required" >*</span></label>
            <input name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email@domain.com" type="text">

            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" type="text">

            <label for="address">Area of Interest </label>
            <input name="address" id="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" type="text">

            <label for="comments">Comments</label>
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder=""></textarea>

            <input name="submit" id="submit" class="submit_btn" value="Submit" type="submit">
            <img src="images/loader.gif" alt="Loader" class="loader">
            <div class="info_msg">
                <p><span class="required">*</span> indicates required field.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="response_msg">
                <p></p>
            </div>
</form>
```

This is the js:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
       $("#formContact").validate({
           ignore: ".ignore",
           rules: {
               name: "required", 
               email: {
                   required: true, 
                   email: true
               }
           }, 

           invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
               $('#formContact').find('#response_msg p').removeClass().addClass('error').html('Please fill all the required fields.');
           }, 
           submitHandler: function (form) {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST", 
                   url: $(form).attr('action'), 
                   data: $(form).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                   beforeSend: function(){
                       $('img.loader').fadeIn();
                   },
                   success: function (data) {

                       var json = $.parseJSON(data);

                       //alert(json.status , json.message);

                       $('#formContact').find('#response_msg p').removeClass().html('');

                       if(json.status !='') {

                           if(json.status == 'success') {
                               $('#formContact').trigger('reset');
                           }                    

                           setTimeout(function(){
                               $('#formContact').find('#response_msg p').removeClass().addClass(json.status).html(json.message).fadeIn();
                           }, 1000);

                       }

                   },
                   error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                       $('#formContact').find('#response_msg p').removeClass().addClass('error').html('Some error occured. Please try again.').fadeIn();
                   },
                   complete: function(){
                       $('img.loader').fadeOut();
                   }
               });
           }
       });
   });
</script>
```

This is the contact-submit.php:

````
    //session_start(); 
    require 'include/include.php';
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $address = trim($_POST['address']);

    $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);

    $errors = array();

    if($name == '' or $email == '' ) {
        $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Please fill all the required fields.');
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }
    else {

        if(strlen($name) < 3) {
            $errors[] = 'Name should be 3 characters long.';    
        }


        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Please enter valid email.';
        } 

        $errors = array_filter($errors);

        if (!empty($errors)) { 
            $message = implode("<br>", $errors);
            $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $message );
            echo json_encode($response);
            exit;    
        }
        else { 
            $mailsubject = "Contact Us Form Details - ".$site_name;
            $sendmessage = "Dear Administrator,<br /><br />     
                <b>Name:</b> $name<br /><br />
                <b>Email:</b> $email<br /><br />
                <b>Phone:</b> $phone <br /><br />
                <b>Address:</b> $address <br /><br />
                <b>Comments:</b> $comments <br /><br />";
            $mail_str = "";
            $mail_str = '<html><head><link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head><body style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;"> <table style="border:1px solid #000000" width="95%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tbody><tr style="background-color:#365744"><td style="padding: 10px; "><a href="#" style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 40px; text-decoration: none; display: block; line-height: normal;">'.$site_name.'</a></td></tr><tr style="background-color:#ffffff"><td style="padding: 10px; ">'.$sendmessage.' </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#383634; color: #fff;"><td style="padding: 10px; ">Thanks! - '.$site_name.'</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>';                

            // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
            $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
            $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

            // Additional headers
            $headers[] = sprintf('From: %s <%s>', $name, $email);

            $headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);

            #echo "<hr/>"; echo $to_mail;echo "<hr/>";echo $mailsubject;echo $mail_str; echo $headers; exit;    

            $emailsend = mail($admin_email, $mailsubject, $mail_str, $headers);

            if($emailsend) {
                $response = array('status' => 'success', 'message' => sprintf('Thank you for your interest in %s. <br /> A representative will be in contact with you shortly', $site_name), 'email_sent' => $emailsend);
                echo json_encode($response);
                exit;
            }
            else {
                $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Some error occured. Please try again.', 'email_sent' => $emailsend);
                echo json_encode($response);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

    #---------------Mail For Admin (Ends)--------------------------------------------------

    //header("Location:thank-you.html");
    exit;
?>```
````

Comment: This rather sounds like your JS code isn’t doing much, and the form gets send “normally” … Are you sure that whatever library/plugin you are using there wants the form to have `novalidate="novalidate"` set …? That sounds a bit counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: inside the `json.status == 'success'` then u can `$('.response_msg').html(json.message)`

Comment: Maybe add `peventDefault()` in your `submitHandler` before the ajax call. You'd need to add the `event` prameter to the `submitHandler` and then do `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Looking at my code there is class="response_msg" and then #response_msg I never updated it. but it doesn't work whether it is a class or id

Comment: Where do you get the `.validate()` function from? Your project can't be loaded as you've pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code class="response_msg" should be id="response_msg" in your form.

You should be setting the header when returning json.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: i added a comment about that. it doesn't matter if everything is a class or id. i forgot to change the code back when i copied it over here. thanks though!

Comment: I've updated my answer. I just noticed that you are not setting the header for json content type.

Comment: Set the header before you return your response. So before your echo json_encode($response);.

Comment: You should be calling preventDefault() and stopPropagation() in your submit handler like was mentioned in the other comment as well. Otherwise you will end up with the normal form submission behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `preventDefault` call. Otherwise, the form is probably being submitted via the normal form POST process after your Ajax is finished and thus is redirecting to the `contact-submit.php` page and you see the echo out of the response on a blank page.

Try this edit:

```php
...
submitHandler: function (form, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST"
...
```

Comment: I just tried that out with no luck. thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I've debugged your code and tested it as working. You need to add the following 4 changes:

1. Specify the data type to jQuery. Add the `dataType` line as below.

`data: $(form).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function(){`

2. Let jQuery do the JSON parsing. Change this:

`success: function (data) {`

To this:

`success: function (json) {`

3. Get rid of this line:

`var json = $.parseJSON(data);`

4. Your `#response_msg` selector is off, because you've given the container a `.response_msg` class, instead of an id. Change this:

`<div id="response_msg">`

To this:

`<div class="response_msg">`

Or change the selectors to refer to the class instead.

And things should then work as expected.